# How to fix: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've seen a lot of "angular" responses to this but not any REACT only ones.

**PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "sdfsdf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sdfsdf sdfsdf sdf Lab Website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "postinstall": "(cd prizes && npm install) ; (cd news && npm install);"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.xxx.edu:SeyLab/xxx.xxx.edu.git"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "author": "Wonyoung So <sdfs@sdfsdf.edu> (http://sdfsdf.so)",
  "contributors": [
    "Wonyoung So"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "gsap": "^1.20.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "jsonp": "^0.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
    "react-collapse": "^4.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.7.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-retina-image": "^2.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.36",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.0.0-beta.36",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.36",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "extracted-loader": "^1.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "react-cond": "git+https://github.com/dsdfsdfs/react-cond.git",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "=2.9.7"
  }
}
```

When I go to

```
npm run start

> senseable_website@1.0.0 start
> NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js

(node:2867) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:111:26)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1626:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:111:17) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost'
}

Node.js v18.7.0
```